# Does empirical mean of the product of two random variables converge to the true mean?

Tags: expected-value, convergence

If we sample $x_i$'s from $X\sim N(0,1)$, and $y_i$'s from $Y\sim N(0,1)$ (the distributions are set to be normal to make things concrete but they can be any distribution), then is it true that

$$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nx_iy_i\rightarrow\mathbb{E}[XY],$$

as $n\rightarrow\infty$ (e.g., by the weak law of large numbers, we would have convergence in probability)?

Comment: Assuming the samples are independent, you are asking about the random variables $Z_i=X_iY_i.$ All the usual theorems directly apply, including the laws of large numbers and the Central Limit Theorem.  Thus, there's not much to say other than to point out you already know the answer, but have only asked a simple question in an obscure way.

Comment: Thanks, you make things clearer for me.

Comment: You need to be sure the conditions of any theorem you apply will hold (it will be so for the WLLN and the CLT in this case, but you should consider how to check it).